# Find roots of $x^4 -6x^3 + 12x^2 - 12 x + 4 = 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots, substitution, quartics

the original equation is:

$$(x^2 + 2)^2 -6x(x^2+2) + 8x^2=0.$$

cannot see how to go solving this. I tried following way to factorise:

$$(x^2+2)(x^2-6x+2) + 8x^2 = 0.$$

But this has no help to solve.

*Thank you people, but I need the thinking process, not the answer.*

Comment: As a thumb rule, if you have an expression which is almost completely factored and you need to find its roots, to expand it is not a good idea.

Comment: For instance, can you find the roots of  $x^4-6x^3+9x^2+1$? What if I tell you that such polynomial is a quadratic polynomial evaluated at $x^2-3x+1$?

Comment: jack daurizo - $x^4 - 3x^3  - 3x^3 + 9x^2 + 1 = (x^3 -3x^2 )(x-3)  + 1$ what now

Comment: *Per l'appunto*. Try the second approach.

Comment: $[x(x-3)]^2 = - 1$ *grazie mille*!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's $$\left(\frac{x^2+2}{x}\right)^2-6\left(\frac{x^2+2}{x}\right)+8=0,$$
which gives
$$\frac{x^2+2}{x}=2$$ and $x\in\{1+i,1-i\}$ or
$$\frac{x^2+2}{x}=4,$$ which gives $x\in\{2+\sqrt2,2-\sqrt2\}$.

Answer (score 6):

In the original version, let $y=x^2+2$. Then, we have $y^2-6xy+8x^2=0$, which gives us $(y-2x)(y-4x)=0$.

Comment: Note: the first sentence is a comment on the question which the author removed, for unknown reasons.

Comment: what do you mean

Comment: @gilly I mean someone left a comment "in the original version, let $y=x^2+2$", and then removed it

Comment: So what was your thought process in factorisation

Comment: @gilly Factoring a quadratic expression needs no thought-process

Comment: implying that i am complete idiot

Comment: @gilly Consider it a quadratic equation in $y$ and consider $x$ as constant

Comment: To me the thought process behind this approach is that it is not genetically possible find nice solutions for quartics, so we need to find some special structure. The structure in this case, is that x and x^2+2 both appear twice, and when you substitute y for the latter, it becomes clearer that the problem is like a quadratic and can be factored.

Answer (score 2):

your equation is equivalent to
$$(x^2-4x+2)(x^2-2x+2)=0$$

Answer (score 1):

One way to find the factorizations others have given is to complete the square.  If you recognize $y^2-6y+9=(y-3)^2$ you can do $(x^2+2)^2-6(x^2+2)+8x^2=((x^2+2)-3x)^2-x^2=(x^2+2-4x)(x^2+2-2x)$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose, instead that the problem was $$(x^2+2)^2 -6t(x^2+2)+8t^2=0$$

Now suppose that $x=t$